# Unemployment Claims vs Monthly Jobs Report

Tags: unemployment

Lately weekly Unemployment claims have been around 700,000.  So Monthly unemployment claims are about 4 x 700,000 or 2,800,000.    YET Jobs Reports say:  The U.S. economy gained 638,000 jobs in October.  Are we really losing    2,800,000 -  638,000  or   2,162,000 jobs monthly?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

On the last inference of the first graph, the unemployment rate is at 6.7%. This means that out of the 164.6 million Americans that the labor force is comprised, 11.2 million are unemployed as of November 2020 (data: Bureau of Labor Statistics[2](https://data.bls.gov/timeseries/LNS14000000)).

This graph and the graph to its right, both indicate that people are beginning to get employed at a dropping rate.

On the following (red) graph you may notice that as of August, fillings for unemployment have remained relatively constant (data: Department of Labor[3](https://www.dol.gov/ui/data.pdf)).

[image]

So the answer I can quickly come up with goes like this; the US is not actually losing 2,000,000 jobs monthly, as the 2nd chart has shown. There might be other incentives at play that encourage people to file for unemployment - perhaps they need to do so in order to receive government handouts even if they didn't work and didn't need to file for unemployment prior to the crisis; meaning they weren't part of the active labor force.